# Get List of Functions and Subs in a class file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to get a list of all of the Functions and Subs in Class file in Visual Studios?  We're making extensive changes and I'd like to have a list in excel so I can use it to keep track of what I've already done.

I'd like to also get a list of every function/sub that references those subs/functions, but I can do that myself if necessary.

So, can this be done in Visual Studios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

**1. Programatically using Reflection and `Type.GetMethods`**

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) page

Here is the example code on that page (I did not author this code, please see the link above)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

' Create a class having two public methods and one protected method.
Public Class MyTypeClass
    Public Sub MyMethods()
    End Sub 'MyMethods
    Public Function MyMethods1() As Integer
        Return 3
    End Function 'MyMethods1
    Protected Function MyMethods2() As [String]
        Return "hello"
    End Function 'MyMethods2
End Class 'MyTypeClass
Public Class TypeMain
    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Dim myType As Type = GetType(MyTypeClass)
        ' Get the public methods.
        Dim myArrayMethodInfo As MethodInfo() = myType.GetMethods((BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        Console.WriteLine((ControlChars.Cr + "The number of public methods is " & myArrayMethodInfo.Length.ToString() & "."))
        ' Display all the public methods.
        DisplayMethodInfo(myArrayMethodInfo)
        ' Get the nonpublic methods.
        Dim myArrayMethodInfo1 As MethodInfo() = myType.GetMethods((BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        Console.WriteLine((ControlChars.Cr + "The number of protected methods is " & myArrayMethodInfo1.Length.ToString() & "."))
        ' Display all the nonpublic methods.
        DisplayMethodInfo(myArrayMethodInfo1)
    End Sub 'Main

    Public Shared Sub DisplayMethodInfo(ByVal myArrayMethodInfo() As MethodInfo)
        ' Display information for all methods.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To myArrayMethodInfo.Length - 1
            Dim myMethodInfo As MethodInfo = CType(myArrayMethodInfo(i), MethodInfo)
            Console.WriteLine((ControlChars.Cr + "The name of the method is " & myMethodInfo.Name & "."))
        Next i
    End Sub 'DisplayMethodInfo
End Class 'TypeMain
```

**2. With Visual Studio IDE and Code Metrics**

1. Right click the Project
2. Calculate Code Metrics
3. In Code Metrics Results pane
4. Right click the Class
5. Open the Selection in Microsoft Excel

Might be an easier option.